# Generate w3 trace-id based on Salesforce request Id

Tags: apex

I am trying to generate a w3 trace-id based on Salesforce request Id. Salesforce request Id is unique from this code:

```
Request reqInfo = Request.getCurrent();
String currentRequestId = reqInfo.getRequestId();
```

However, the generated string has 22 characters and it is a general string. Something like: 4cYtGvkjpajdg-dcTQqyxV

However, w3 trace-id is a 16 bit hex string which has 32 characters but it is all hex string. Something like this: 4bf92f3577b34da6a3ce929d0e0e4736

If I directly encode request id into hex it will be 44 characters long. I am wondering whether there is an approach for us to generate a trace id based on what we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a reasonably unique 32-hex-digit string with MD5:

```
String input = '4cYtGvkjpajdg-dcTQqyxV';
String output = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(
  Crypto.generateDigest(
    'MD5', 
     Blob.valueOf(input)
  )
);
```

This would output something like:

```
2d211b3eeb61e38ac46e0535c56e14bc
```

Note that MD5 is considered "broken" in the traditional sense (it's easy to fabricate collisions, and thus unsuitable for digest/signing), but it is perfect for your use case, as there's very little chance of two trace ids outputting the same values "randomly."

The great thing about digests is that the output bits are always guaranteed to be a certain width, as we're basically just calculating a "fingerprint" of a certain size; it is not reversible, meaning you can't get the original back out, either.